# Unable to show favicon in NodeJS Express app

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to show favicon in my application but its not visible I am using `serve-favicon` package.I am running application on localhost
below is my code:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use("/public", express.static('public')); 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname,'public','image','favicon.ico')));

app.get('/',(req,res) => {

    res.send("Hello");
    
});

app.listen(port, () => {

   console.log(`App is running at ${port}`);
});
```

Someone let me know what is wrong in above code.

Comment: why don't you just display favicon on each front-end page?

Comment: Can you change their order ?
`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="Favicon_Image_Location"/>`
This line should come first than any other middleware functions.